# SharpDX 2.5 in DirectX11 in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, directx-11, sharpdx

I'm trying to implement DirectX 11 using SharpDX 2.5 into WPF. 
Sadly http://directx4wpf.codeplex.com/ and http://sharpdxwpf.codeplex.com/ don't work properly with SharpDX 2.5. I was also not able to port the WPFHost DX10 sample to DX11 and the full code package of this example is down: http://www.indiedev.de/wiki/DirectX_in_WPF_integrieren

Can someone suggest another way of implementing?

Comment: Why can't you port the DX10 sample? Details will help others help you. Also, here's a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/9095089/1339280

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SharpDX supports WPF via [SharpDXElement](https://github.com/sharpdx/Toolkit/blob/master/Source/Toolkit/SharpDX.Toolkit.Game/Desktop/SharpDXElement.cs).

Take a look in the [Samples](https://github.com/sharpdx/SharpDX-Samples/tree/e904360d12554f421ed683b429a802c0f7ae015a) repository at the `Toolkit.sln` - all projects that have `WPF` in their name use `SharpDXElement` as rendering surface:

- `MiniCube.WPF` - demonstrates basic SharpDX-WPF integration;
- `MiniCube.SwitchContext.WPF` - demonstrates basic scenario when lifetime of the Game instance is different from the lifetime of SharpDXElement (in other words - when there is need to switch game rendering on another surface).
- `MiniCube.SwitchContext.WPF.MVVM` - same as above, but more 'MVVM-way'.

Update: SharpDX.Toolkit has been deprecated and it is not maintained anymore. It is moved to a separate repository. The Toolkit samples were deleted, however I changed the link to a changeset where they are still present.

Comment: The links to SharpDXElement are broken.  Please update them.

Comment: Also, I'm having a hard time finding toolkit.sln or any projects with WPF in their names.

Answer (score 3):

You can still use http://sharpdxwpf.codeplex.com/.

In order to work properly with SharpDX 2.5.0 you need to do a few modifications.

1) In project Sharp.WPF in class DXUtils.cs in method

```
Direct3D11.Buffer CreateBuffer<T>(this Direct3D11.Device device, T[] range)
```

add this line

```
stream.Position = 0;
```

just after

```
stream.WriteRange(range);
```

So fixed method looks like this:

```
public static Direct3D11.Buffer CreateBuffer<T>(this Direct3D11.Device device, T[] range)
        where T : struct
    {
        int sizeInBytes = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(T));
        using (var stream = new DataStream(range.Length * sizeInBytes, true, true))
        {
            stream.WriteRange(range);
            stream.Position = 0; // fix
            return new Direct3D11.Buffer(device, stream, new Direct3D11.BufferDescription
            {
                BindFlags = Direct3D11.BindFlags.VertexBuffer,
                SizeInBytes = (int)stream.Length,
                CpuAccessFlags = Direct3D11.CpuAccessFlags.None,
                OptionFlags = Direct3D11.ResourceOptionFlags.None,
                StructureByteStride = 0,
                Usage = Direct3D11.ResourceUsage.Default,
            });
        }
    }
```

2) And in class D3D11 in file D3D11.cs
rename this

```
m_device.ImmediateContext.Rasterizer.SetViewports(new Viewport(0, 0, w, h, 0.0f, 1.0f));
```

into this

```
  m_device.ImmediateContext.Rasterizer.SetViewport(new Viewport(0, 0, w, h, 0.0f, 1.0f));
```

i.e. SetViewports into SetViewport.

And it should work now.